# Setting time in TimePicker and comparing it to calendar.hour and minute?

Tags: android, time, calendar, timepicker

I have a TimePicker that I need to grab the hour and minute from (-after the user specifies a time and hits the done button) and then compare it to the current hour and minute, doing an action if those two times match up.

Currently I'm using:

```
int calendarHour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    int calendarMinute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
```

to get the current hour and minute. After doing a lot of searching, I'm confused on the format of time working compared to a string/int on android.

How do I grab the hour and minute from the TimePicker? How do I check IF the TimePicker time and Calendar time match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `Calendar.HOUR` is represented in the range [0,12), you need to use `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY` to get it in the [0,23) range that is similar to the range that `TimePicker.getCurrentHour()` returns.

```
int calendarHour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int calendarMinute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

int timePickerHour = timePicker.getCurrentHour();
int timePickerMinute = timePicker.getCurrentMinute();

if (calendarHour == timePickerHour && calendarMinute == timePickerMinute) {
    // Same 
}
```

[TimePicker Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html)